# Soft destroy raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed - The Rails 4 Way book

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement very basic "soft deletion" without gems like paranoia. Following "The Rails 4 Way" book http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2220311&seqNum=2 I've added to a model:

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy { self.update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.now); false}
end
```

That should be enough for me (that's why I don't want to use any external gems).
However, it causes a problem:

```
[3] pry(main)> b = Branch.last
  Branch Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "branches".* FROM "branches"  ORDER BY "branches"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Branch:0xa0f28b4
 ...
[4] pry(main)> b.destroy!
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "branches" SET "deleted_at" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "branches"."id" = ?  [["deleted_at", "2015-03-24 08:09:32.863888"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-24 08:09:32.864880"], ["id", 6856]]
   (0.3ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed: ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:184:in `destroy!'
```

My `Branch` model has no `dependent: :whatever` associations and no validations.
After reading documentation I found that this is correct since callback returns false and execution stops here.
But this is not what I need because of `rollback` and no update performed.
Is this an error in book or mine?

Answer (score 1):

See the `destroy!` [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy), it says:

> If the before_destroy callback return false the action is cancelled and destroy! raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed

See your `before_destroy` callback, you are returning `false`:

```
before_destroy { self.update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.now); false}
```

Change this into:

```
before_destroy { self.update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.now) }
```

**Update**:

You can not implement soft delete this easily, both `destroy` and `delete` removes data from database. You will have to re-implement the `destroy` method as well as implement a new method like `really_destroy` for removing record from database. To me, it looks like reinventing the wheel. I will suggest you to study the [`paranoia`](https://github.com/radar/paranoia/blob/rails4/lib/paranoia.rb) codebase to see if re-implementing the whole thing is worthy.

Comment: Without returning false it actually deletes the record (after updating it) which is not what I need

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this using callbacks but you could overwrite the destroy method instead:

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  def destroy
    run_callbacks :destroy
      update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.now) or return false
      @destroyed = true
      freeze
    end
  end
end
```

Using this method all destroy-related methods would still work as expected, except the record would not be destroyed.

Comment: This will not run the callbacks and moreover what if I have associations with dependent :destroy?

Comment: Mhh thats a problem. It work to wrap the code inside destroy with `run_callback :destroy do ... end ` I guess

Comment: It will not destroy the dependents also, since you ignored `destroy_associations`. Envoking `destroy_associations` in your current `destroy` action won't help you either, since destroy method won't be available on associated models. You will need to extend `ActiveRecord::Base` in that case.

Comment: That's true but this should not be a problem since he stated that there are no associations. Handling dependencies really depends on the use case. I would say using `destroy_associations` would be the easiest way.